# App crash when navigating through activities

Tags: android, kotlin

So i've been trying to figure out how to switch activities in android studio using kotlin and i encountered a crash while doing it, because when i want to switch the activity it doesn't work an crashed instead without errors in the terminal. Hope i can get an answer, thanks in advance!

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.activitynavigator

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var firstPageBtn : Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        firstPageBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnFirstPage)

        firstPageBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,SecondPage::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

second page main activity:

```
package com.example.activitynavigator

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class SecondPage : AppCompatActivity()  {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_page)
    }
}
```

first page xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFirstPage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First page button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

second page xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSecondPage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second page button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `finish()` after `startActivity(intent)`?

Comment: Yes i did, in fact i added it before the app crashed for the first time, and now i removed ti too, but still the same problem and I dont know why becuase when i did the android tutorial worked just fine.

Comment: You should add a crash log

Comment: Did you add the `<activity>` tag with the new activity in **AndroidManifest.xml**? More infos here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#CreateActivity

Comment: That was the problem, i didn't started a new acitivity just created the sml file, thanks for the help!